# how to bind data to listview in asp.net using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lsvNews" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lsvNews_PagePropertiesChanging">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href='<%#Eval("Hyperlink") %>' target="_blank"><%#Eval("Title") %></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%#string.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", Eval("CreatedDate"))%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and function get data using jquery

```
function GetNews(pageIndex) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
        data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) { //????? }
```

function get data in codebehind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(int pageIndex)
{
    DataSet ds = CreateDataSet(pageIndex);
    return ds.GetXml();
}
```

Please tell me know the way bind data to `ListView` by code in function `OnSuccess`, thank :)

Answer (score 0):

A listview control is by definition a server side control, and cannot be databound on the client side.  OnSuccess would need to to post the data back to a WebMethod that would then bind the data to the listview.

Instead of that, why not just make these changes to your webmethod something like this?

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(int pageIndex)
{

    DataSet ds = CreateDataSet(pageIndex);
    lsvNews.datasource = ds;
    lsvNews.DataBind();
    return "Success";
}
```

It could be that I am missing the point, so I apologize if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(int pageIndex)
{
    DataSet ds = CreateDataSet(pageIndex);
    lsvNews.datasource = ds;
    lsvNews.DataBind();
    return "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static DataSet GetDataFromDatabase(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds, "Customers");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("PageCount");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageCount");
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    dt.Rows[0][0] = cmd.Parameters["@PageCount"].Value;
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                  
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.